# How to highlight text in lyx?

Tags: lyx, highlighting

I want to highlight some text in lyx just like in word/docs.
I can't find the way to do this in lyx, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `\colorbox` to do it (you will need the `\usepackage{color}` in your LaTeX Preamble to use this). To do so you need to follow this pattern:

```
\colorbox{<colorname>}{text or math}
```

in order to do this quickly you can use this shortcut (works for hebrew but you can change the langue to your convenience):

```
command-sequence ert-insert; self-insert \colorbox{green}{ ; escape;unicode-insert 0x0020; ert-insert; self-insert } ; char-right;char-right;unicode-insert 0x0020; language Hebrew;
```